# Recursive Function in Javascript showing NaN

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I'm experimenting with recursive functions in javascript which takes a number and outputs the factorial of that number. I decided to go for simplicity and do something like this:

```
function myFunc(n)
{   
    if(n > 1){
        return (n * myFunc(n - 1));
}

}

console.log(myFunc(4));
```

yet console.log() keeps outputing NaN. What am I doing wrong please? Everything looks right to me.

Comment: what about the `else` branch of your code, where `n <= 1`? try `else return 1` :D

Comment: You have no return for `else` case. That's why it is by default returning `undefined` for "else" and `undefined` + a number = `NaN`.

Answer (score 3):

I quess you are trying to implement factorial using recursive function.
If you trace your code manually, you'll find that eventually you will call `myFunc(1)` and it doesn't have any `return` as your code only return when `n > 1`. So all you need to do is to add a return for `n == 1` (or any possible `n` value).

```
function myFunc(n) {   
    if (n > 1) {
        return (n * myFunc(n - 1));
    }

    /* else if (n <= 1) then return 1. 
     * This is commented because if the first condition fails, 
     * it will continue to execute the rest from here.
     */
    return 1;
}

console.log(myFunc(4));  // output 4!, which is equal to 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24
```

Comment: can you please point me to a video that teaches me how to trace code please?

Comment: @JeffKyei Well sorry, I don't know if there are such videos. But I'll try to explain in text.
Firstly, lets define `myFunc(n)` as `f(n)` for shorter naming. Let the tracing begin in computation order. `f(4)` = `4 * f(3)`, And then, because function rank is higher than multiplication, it will try compute the `f(3)` first.
= `4 * 3 * f(2)` = `4 * 3 * 2 * f(1)` = `4 * 3 * 2 * 1` = `12 * 2 * 1` = `24 * 1` = `24`
Notice `f(1)` returns 1 because we define the implicit case to return 1